# Text Selection Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer-9, textselection

I have tried with no success to disable text selection in this code. EDIT(Thanks techfoobar): http://jsfiddle.net/5uG63/3/ The only element that I have applied the majority of the code to is the element that has the three in it. The rest of them you will be able to highlight. I know none of the dragging functions work seeing this is a snippet of a much larger block of code that would be hard to post seeing it is getting the elements through Ajax. I am not really worried about the users selecting the text for the sense of possibly taking the information, but sometimes when the text get selected it interferes with the drag and drop function.

For the element containing the three, and all the others when they are enabled, there seems to be only one case that this happens. Using Internet Explorer, if you were to click in the center of the white space between the two boxes at the far left side, and then drag your mouse across to the far right of the two boxes, the  number 3 then becomes selected. I am using Internet Explorer 9.

I tried disabling it in the CSS, which seems to have little effect. I think that the issue is that it is being selected from outside the div that it is in.

That is the CSS that I used: [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't just drop everything into the HTML section of jsFiddle. Put the CSS & JavaScript in the right sections and leave just the contents of the `body` in the HTML panel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I actually did try doing that, then it stopped functioning. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Here's a proper version of your fiddle. :-) http://jsfiddle.net/5uG63/3/

Answer (score 0):

For your table, you have specified `onselectstart="select()"`. You should change this to `onselectstart="return select()"` (note the **return**) to ensure that the **false** you are returning from the *select()* function is notified to the browser, which in turn blocks selection.

Check this *fiddle*: http://jsfiddle.net/5uG63/4/

*Note:* This will work only if you start the selection from the element itself. If you start selecting from outside your table, things will still get selected.

Comment: Yeah, I have a solution for selection within the element that is functioning. My issue that I am having is the specific case where the element is selected from the outside.Thanks for your help!